# First of three comboboxes takes old value on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selecteditem

### Setup:

I have tree comboboxes on a Windows Form and they all have the exact same properties set. They have a separate BindingSource and these sources get their items from a DataContext. They all have the same items, only show it in another language. Here's some sample code for the setup:

```
var allTitles = dbContext.GetTitles();

bindingSourceNL = allTitles.OrderBy(t => t.TitleNL);
DucthBox.DataSource = bindingSourceNL;
//This goes the same for the FR and DE comboboxes
//They have THE SAME set of data, only a different display property
```

When selecting an item from any of the comboboxes, the other two must get their corresponding title. Each ComboBox has its SelectedIndexChanged-event and calls the same method in which the corresponding title in the other two are set:

```
public void SetCbValues(object selectedItem)
{
    if (!suspend)
    {
        suspend = true;

        //In real code there's a null-check
        var selectedTitle = (Title)selectedItem;
        DutchBox.SelectedIndex = DutchBox.FindStringExact(selectedTitle.TitleNL);
        FrenchBox.SelectedIndex = FrenchBox.FindStringExact(selectedTitle.TitleFR);
        GermanBox.SelectedIndex = GermanBox.FindStringExact(selectedTitle.TitleDE);

        suspend = false;
    }
}
```

### Binding event handlers:

Binding of the events is done like this:

```
DutchBox.SelectedIndexChanged += DutchBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
//Same goes for the other two
```

Unsubscribing is done like this:

```
DutchBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= DutchBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
//Same goes for the other two
```

### Sample data:

This is only a simulation of representable data that I use:

```
var titles = new List<Title>
{
    new Title
    {
        TitleNL = "1 - Medewerker",
        TitleFR = "1 - Employé",
        TitleDE = "1 - Mitarbeiter"
    },
    new Title
    {
        TitleNL = "2 - Arbeider",
        TitleFR = "2 - Travailleur",
        TitleDE = "2 - Arbeiter"
    },
    new Title
    {
        TitleNL = "3 - Bediende",
        TitleFR = "3 - Greffier",
        TitleDE = "3 - Schreiber"
    },
}
```

This list is bound to each ComboBox and depending on which one, the right language is shown.

### Problem:

When I change the title in de first ComboBox (Dutch) and press the button on my form, the old values are taken and submitted. When I change one of the other two comboboxes, this doesn't occur. Also when I change a value of the other two, change the Dutch one and press the button, the last chosen value of the other was submitted.

Simulation:

- On load, selecteditem is `null` -> select Dutch first item and submit:
  `null` is submitted.
- On load, selecteditem is `null` -> select French third item -> select Dutch second item and submit: second item is submitted.
- On load, selecteditem is `null` -> select third Dutch item -> select Dutch fifth item and submit: `null` is submitted

Does anyone have an idea what might cause this and how to solve this?

Comment: please show how you bind these comboboxes to event handler. Also does changing selected items in other boxes trigger event?

Comment: Fro the binding, check my updated answer (section 'binding event handlers'). Yes, the events are triggered on the other ones as well.